# Radio button inside virtual scrolling angular 7 selecting multiple radio buttons

Tags: angular7, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I am using virtual scrolling feature of angular 7. I am trying to add input type radio inside virtual scroll bar. So multiple radio button are getting selected when we do the scrolling. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer templatecachesize  :0 workes for me